# Does the Samsung Galaxy S2 support DC-HSDPA

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, 3g

I have a **Samsung Galaxy S2** running **Cyanogenmod 10.1.3** which equates to **Android 4.2.2**.

I would like to know if my phone will support **DC-HSDPA** or not? Will it *just work*?

Is there anything I would need to do in order for it to support **DC-HSDPA** like upgrade the **RIL** or is it just not capable at the hardware level?

Comment: I don't think it would be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

After some testing over the weekend with a service provider who provides **DC-HSDPA** I can confirm that the **Samsung Galaxy S2** does not support the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 and using the Dutch T-Mobile NL network. When I open the app "Network Signal Info" it shows (DC)HSPA+ and the networksymbol shows H+, so it looks like that this phone supports dual channel HSPA+.

Answer (score -2):

They say on the site that it does not support 4G or the faster DC-HSDPA. Having an S2 myself, it would be great if we get a hack for it with the the cfw. Just gotta have hope.

Comment: Sorry, but what is `cfw`?

Comment: What site? Can you provide a link?